# Change Branch Through Web Dashboard for CC.NET

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I was wondering what other people might have done to facilitate the alteration of which branch is being built via the web dashboard for CruiseControl.NET to quickly change the branch code is deployed based on. We are specifically using SVN.

We want to be able to, on the fly, change an environment to build a branch X to branch Y quickly. We do not want to allow developers the ability to access the build server directly to change the ccnet.config file; but, want to allow them access to the web dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not possible in the stock version of cc.net

What you can do is to **monitor the tags folder.**
So whenever you are tagging the repository (from a branch or trunk), you will run an integration.

I hope this will help you.